# Find closest previous and next date from a list

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a list of object, in which one of the property is Date. I need to find the closest previous Date and closest next Date by having a reference to certain date.

Which would be the best way to do this? If possible i would like to avoid looping through the List multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution which comes intuitively:

1. Take your **current date**
2. Create **previous closest date** with minimum possible value for date; the same for **next closest date** with maximum possible value
3. Loop through an array and check: if a date is less than **current date** and later than **previous closest date**, reassign **previous closest date**; the similar logic is applied for the next date

It will let you find both dates in a single loop (`O(N)`).

Another simple and clear solution, but algorithmically worse (`O(N * log N)`):

1. Sort your array
2. Find you **current date**
3. The previous item and the next item will be obviously closest previous and closest next date

Implementation is up to you.
Come back when you implement it and tell us how you are doing.